# Spring boot MVC: RequestMapping isn't recognized in Spring boot 2.1.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Can someone answer this silly question - How to configure Thymeleaf in Spring boot release 2.1.4?

I have declared the right dependencies:

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also the config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("org.mystuff.myproj")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Init extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
```

And the controller looks regular:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/a")
public class IndexController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);

    @PostConstruct
    private void test() {
        logger.info("********************************************************************");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    private String index() {
        return "index2";
    }
```

I do see that the @Controller bean gets initiated (the "*****..."), but when I try to locate in the logs the "mapped" or atleast something related, the only thing I find is:

```
2019-04-23 15:55:15 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor: spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning

2019-04-23 15:55:16 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] WelcomePageHandlerMapping.<init>: Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]
```

And I'm failing to find an answer to the "What has changed" question.

After a while I realized that Spring Boot 2.1.4 requires TomCat 9, while I was using 8.5.

After this I started to get progress, but still the Thymeleaf isn't working, and if /templates has a index.html, the default Resolver is used, which ignores Thymeleaf's "fragments" and stuff (loads like a regular html page).

Comment: I don't think it is `thymeleaf` related .

Comment: @want2learn, yes and no. First issue was with me firstly making the project on Spring Boot 1.3.8, and then at some point deciding to move to 2.1.4, while working on the service layer and not noticing the controller. So moving to Tomcat 9.0 atleast started to execute binding with the RequestMapping (but not showing in the logs). Second... the second one, where I actually cannot get a successful thymeleaf experience, I'm still looking how to fix.